# The import java.awt.Taskbar cannot be resolved and Taskbar cannot be resolved

Tags: java, awt, taskbar

```
`if(!Taskbar.isTaskbarSupported()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Taskbar isn't supported!","ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Taskbar");
        jf.setSize(500, 250);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        Taskbar.getTaskbar().setIconImage();`
```

Even I imported still it gives me error on Taskbar. So I'm not able to use Taskbar.
I want to display default icon on Taskbar but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

`java.awt.Taskbar` class introduced in JDK 9.

In its documentation:

```
public class Taskbar extends Object

Since:
    9
```

If the import cannot be resolved, that means you are porbably building with JDK 8 (hopefully its not earlier version :) )

Comment: is there any solution to use Taskbar in JDK 8. 

I want to display the icon on taskbar.

Comment: **17.0.4.1** this version is install in my PC. @Geoge Z

Comment: @AnjaliYadav As far as I know, there is no way to use the Taskbar in JDK 8. Installed Java version, and used Java version is a different thing. You can change the used version to JDK 9 and Taskbar import will be resolved.